# Vertical UICollectionView inside Custom TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to display vertical collection view in Custom UITableViewCell. I am exactly looking for design like iPhone Wish shopping app i.e Displaying the list of products(`UICollectionView`).

By clicking the product navigating to detailed page showing the product information(`UITableView`) and again list of products(`UICollectionView`).

I don't know how to approach this functionality.
 
By using AFTabledCollection I am able to do vertical collection view but `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is not calculating height for this custom cell.

Am I following the right direction ?

Comment: tableView will not calculate automatic height cause of collection vertical height you'll have to calculate height based on your number of cells in one cell and change collection view constraint height at run time. I am using this on various screens and it works flawlessly.